# Distributed components lifecycle management

Tags: java, spring, distributed

My company has plans to implement a clustered system with a lot of services that will be deployed automatically in different machines and will interconnect with each other (SOA style). Sometimes the services will have interdependencies.

For example:
Service B (application) can be started up only when the Service A (Database) is up and running.

Each service is planned to be run as a different java process, possibly deployed as a WAR (inside dedicated tomcat) or even without web at all.

For now we have all the services in the same WAR and only single tomcat that deploys the WAR.
All the services are defined via Spring and Spring manages dependencies for us.

So I'm asking myself whether exist some frameworks that will help to manage the services in a distributed environment as I've described above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ZooKeeper**.

Correction, use Netflix's **Curator**, a framework on top of zookeeper which simplifies the work with it.

Where I work I recently implemented a `Coordinator` class which has two methods:

`waitForDependencies` - a synchronic method that checks for the liveness of the current service's dependnecies and blocks the current thread until notified that all dependency services are alive. The liveness check is done by verifying the existence of nodes which are created by the depenedency services, at the end of their initializing process, by calling `notifyUp`

`notifyUp` - a synchronic method that notifies the world that the current service that calls that method is alive. The notification is done by creating an ephemeral (temporal, stays alive just as long as the connection in which it was created is alive) node in the zk cluster, which is looked for by other services which depend on it, using `waitForDependencies`

Answer (score 2):

**Netflix** released their open source tool - [Asgard](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/06/asgard-web-based-cloud-management-and.html) that manages and deploys instances to a cloud. It is tightly coupled with EC2 (the last time I checked). Depending on whether you deploy to the amazon cloud you might find that useful. I'm unaware if it supports dependencies but it does manage deployments on a distributed environment. Netflix does talk about service dependencies a lot on their blog, so the deployment solution *might* have a feature to solve for that.

I'm not aware of any other service / framework that does this. If you were to write this on your own I guess you could configure a couple of **Jenkins** tasks that deploy services. One task can depend on another to simulate the service dependency. Pinging URL endpoints can check if Service A exists before B is deployed.

There's another way to look at this. You would not need to check for dependency if you ensure your services are all running properly. Monitoring tools like **Nagios** can help here. Troubleshooting faulty services immediately can help you focus on deploying Service A instead of checking your dependencies on each deployment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a valuable information. 10 points from me here with no doubt :) I'll check out the netflix, although we are not planning to run on EC2. I don't think Jenkins can help here, because I believe that its work is to build the project but not to deploy in the production environment. I would prefer to work with some service that (probably) installs agents on each machine and then manages everything by itself (+ provides monitoring if possible :))

Comment: Some folks do use Jenkins to deploy to prod using maven tasks like `tomcat:deploy`. Software that uses agents and dependency management will surely look a lot less tangled. Good luck and let us know if you find what you're looking for.